# Ruby methods returning results in repl.it but not when I run the program

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm very new to ruby and I have been writing some simple programs. I've noticed that alot of my programs are creating no returned values when I try to run them through the command line, but seem to be working perfectly when I use repl.it for testing. For example:

```
def rev(a)

b = []

c = []

b = a.scan(/\w+/)

c = b.map {|x| x.reverse }

return c.join(' ')

end

rev('hello')
```

If I use `puts c.join(' ')` the answer will appear but it's not being returned which is what I need to happen. I have a feeling this is something very simple. Any help is appreciated, I've had to create some weird and blocky work arounds to make my other programs work but have limited what I've been able to do.

I'm making this program to fulfill some rspec specifications that were given to me, so simply printing or putting the answer isn't enough, I need the final term evaluated to be the answer.

Comment: Yes, it is returning it. You just don't know how to receive it, apparently.

Comment: *I figured it out. Apparently I should have used yield to map and split the string.

Answer (score 1):

That's because repl.it shows you the results of your statements, which Ruby does not do automatically.

Ruby *can* do this though, try finding the program called "IRB" (which stands for "Interactive Ruby"). If you put your program into it you will get the desired results.

Although you can see that it really is returning the value:

```
puts(rev('hello'))
```

repl.it is simply automatically showing you the result of the last expression.

On an unrelated note, here are some tips for you:

- Use indentation - in your code it is very hard to see which lines belong to the function
- Name your variables descriptive names, so that you know what they're for when you read your code later
- You don't need to type `return` because Ruby automatically returns the last statement

Comment: I am writing this program to fulfill some Rspec specifications. Unfortunately all my examples are still failing, I think because of the line that follows a puts. Do you have any further insight? Also, thanks for the tips.

Comment: @user Umm... sorry, I don't know what Rspec is. Could you explain what that is?

Comment: Its a Behavior Driven Development gem. I've been given specifications, and I need to build a program around it.

Comment: @user Well, what are those specifications?

Comment: describe "rev" do
    it "reverses the string returned by the default block" do
      result = rev do
        "hello"
      end
      result.should == "olleh"
    end

Comment: @user2684405: Your problem is here: `rev do "hello" end`. That method doesn't take a block, it takes a string.

Comment: It takes a string that gets turned into an array that in turn gets turned into a string again at the end.

Comment: @user But it's supposed to take a block. Not a string.

Comment: @user2684405: It doesn't matter what's done with the string. The point is that `rev do "hello" end` is not how you call `rev` with a string argument.

Comment: @Chuck: You're right, apparently we were supposed to use yield to make the test pass.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby method returns the value of the last statement automatically. If you change

```
return c.join(' ')
```

to

```
puts c.join(' ')
```

It will try to return the return value of `puts`, which is not what you want. By the way, you can omit `return` in this case. Simply put

```
c.join(' ')
```

as the last statement, the method will use that as return value.

Comment: I tried that c.join(' '), still nothing is being returned. Using puts returns a line after the answer. I need the answer to be the last thing evaluated.

Comment: @user2684405 When you say `return`, did you mean to print the contents ? That's not `return`, you may call the method like `puts rev('hello')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the return value of a method, you must store it in a variable:

```
answer = rev('hello')
```

If you want to see the answer—as you do inside IRB (the "repl") then you must ask Ruby to output it:

```
p answer    # Print the result of calling `answer.inspect`
puts answer # Print the result of calling `answer.to_s`
```